# How to run sql from a Mac

Tags: sql, database, vmware

I have a MacBook Pro and want to learn more about sql, I understand I cannot run sql from a Mac, what should I install VMware, linux, windows 10? Can someone walk me through this

Comment: You understand wrongly. :) It is perfectly possible to install MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite3 on Mac. The one you can't install is Microsoft SQL Server, and even that can likely be _accessed_ from Mac as a client.

Comment: You certainly can run SQL from a Mac.

Comment: See https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+mac&atb=v110-5_b&ia=web

Comment: and https://duckduckgo.com/?q=postgresql+mac&atb=v110-5_b&ia=web

Comment: What do you recommend I install? Any articles or books you recommend to get started on learning?

Comment: mssql on a mac via docker https://medium.com/@reverentgeek/sql-server-running-on-a-mac-3efafda48861

Comment: Main thing with SQL to understand set theory. Joe Celko's Thinking in Sets: Auxiliary, Temporal, and Virtual Tables in SQL is good. https://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celkos-Thinking-Sets-Management/dp/0123741378?tag=duckduckgo-d-20

Comment: Software recommendations have their own site and are off topic here, but if you want to learn SQL in general and not a specific engine, I suggest getting one that is very strict about things and has understandable error messages, like PostgreSQL, instead of popular but permissive and “I’ll let you shoot yourself in foot easily”, like MySQL.

Comment: I'd recommend installing HomeBrew to start with, then MySql and Sequel Pro, and then Postgres and PSequel. HomeBrew will enabe you to install many standard unix applications on your Mac. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks guys, this was a lot of help! Keith would you be able to give me the link for HomeBrew

Comment: https://postgresapp.com/

Comment: Start with https://brew.sh/ which will allow you to install a variety of programs easily; then `brew install postgresql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is just domain specific language (primarily) for relational databases.  What you need to decide is *what* RDBMS, which in turn implements SQL, you would like to use.[1]  Standalone implementations like SQLite definitely run on the Mac (many of Apple's own applications like Mail use it as their database.)  For the more complex client/server RDBMS systems (i.e. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL/MariaDB, etc.) you will at least need to install client-side drivers (often in the form of ODBC, JDBC or native drivers) and then either connect to an existing[1] database or install your own database server.

Since it sounds like you're just getting started, I'd highly recommend starting with a standalone database such as SQLite which you should be able to get to by opening a terminal window and typing 'sqlite3' at the prompt.  This will allow you to jump right in and focus on learning SQL itself rather than dealing with getting a full-blown client/server database server up and running.  (move on to that later if you find it needed/interesting/useful to you)

[1] unless you need to use an existing database, at work for example, in which case you'll need to find out the various details about the server and database in order to connect to it.  In this case, you'll need to find a point of contact (often a DBA) to provide this information.